# How can I compare two strings in java and define which of them is smaller than the other alphabetically?

Tags: java

I want to use the binary search algorithm to search the string which has been entered by the user in a very big sorted file. I can not compare the string which has been entered by the user with the string which has been located in the middle line of the file to continue my binary search.

For example, if the user's string is `abcda` and the file's string is `abcza`, it is obvious that the user's string is smaller than the file's string. How is it implemented in java? it will be great if you can help me with a sample code.

Comment: You should specify if you need this to work only with English (ASCII) strings, or if the input can potentially be international. Determining which string sorts before another is quite complex, in the latter case.

Answer (score 150):

You can use

```
str1.compareTo(str2);
```

If *str1* is lexicographically less than *str2*, `a negative number` will be returned, `0` if equal or `a positive number` if *str1* is greater.

E.g.,

```
"a".compareTo("b"); // returns a negative number, here -1
"a".compareTo("a"); // returns  0
"b".compareTo("a"); // returns a positive number, here 1
"b".compareTo(null); // throws java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: No. The contract of java.util.Comparable says that it will return a negative integer if the first one is lesser than the second one, and a positive integer if greater. But not necessarily -1 and 1.

Comment: Thanks. But if the first string is "</s> abc" and the second string is "abc". How can I compare "<" with "a"?

Comment: @sylvester, that's a completely different problem. You need to sanitize your strings before comparison using your favourite method.

Comment: @sylvester: The compareTo method of String simply compares the unicode values of the individual characters, thus `'<'` (= 60) is smaller than `'a'` (= 97). As said, if you want to sort both as `abc`, you'll have to strip off the tags and spaces. And you probably want to use a Collator for your language on the result.

Answer (score 6):

If you would like to ignore case you could use the following:

```
String s = "yip";
String best = "yodel";
int compare = s.compareToIgnoreCase(best);
if(compare < 0){
    //-1, --> s is less than best. ( s comes alphabetically first)
}
else if(compare > 0 ){
// best comes alphabetically first.
}
else{
    // strings are equal.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Haven't you heard about the `Comparable` interface being implemented by `String` ? If no, try to use

```
"abcda".compareTo("abcza")
```

And it will output a good root for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
String bigString = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
            System.out.println("... ");
            String sentence = sc.nextLine();
            if(bigString == null || sentence.compareTo(bigString) > 0) {
                bigString = sentence;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("...: " + bigString);
```