# Doing a greater than or equal filter in stream().filter

Tags: java, filter, stream

I am trying to do a stream() filter to only pull records where the string FedwireTagLabel field is greater than "1520".  here is the code that I currently have:

```
         FedwireMessage filterFinancials = financialMessageRecords.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getFedwireTagLabel() >= "1520")
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
```

This is an error.  Do you know what is the processing in stream().filter() that you can do for a greater than or equal to on a string field?

Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two `String` here. You need to convert the label to an `Integer`.

```
 FedwireMessage filterFinancials = financialMessageRecords.stream()
            .filter(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getFedwireTagLabel()) >= 1520)
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
```

Indeed, using `>=` on `String` call the method [CompareTo](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/string_compareto.htm) which return `-1`, `0` or `1` according to the alphabetic default comparison.

For more info, look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153527/3780625).

Best